# Property not found on target property Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, binding, maui

I am implementing a simple page that displays a list of elements to be clicked, using the ListView type. I have the following XAML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BoxingTimer"
             x:Class="BoxingTimer.WorkoutsPage">


    <ListView  x:Name="WorkoutCategoriesListView" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:WorkoutsViewModel.WorkoutCategories}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:WorkoutCategory">

                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"
                          Detail="{Binding Description}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

The list source is a list of "WorkoutCategory", which I indicated with the x:DataType="local:WorkoutCategory" attribute.

```
public sealed class WorkoutCategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the application, it works but the binding failures are reported:

> 'Name' property not found on 'BoxingTimer.WorkoutsViewModel'

> 'Description' property not found on 'BoxingTimer.WorkoutsViewModel'

It seems that the app is looking for the properties in the view model bound to the page, but not in the WorkoutCategory class as it should. Obviously I must be missing/misunderstanding something? Thanks for any help in this matter

Comment: Could you try moving `x:DataType="local:WorkoutCategory"` to the `TextCell`, I think it doesn't work on the `DataTemplate`

Comment: Is `WorkoutsViewModel.WorkoutCategories` declared `static`? Also as a test, if you REMOVE ALL `x:DataType` declarations from your xaml, does the error message change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind the data to a ListView you can follow the steps below.

First, you can Create a `model class` and you already create it.

```
public sealed class WorkoutCategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
}
```

Second, you should create a `ViewModel` to handle the data.

```
  public class MyViewModel
    {
        public  ObservableCollection<WorkoutCategory> WorkoutCategories { get; set; }
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            WorkoutCategories = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
            WorkoutCategories.Add(new WorkoutCategory() { Name = "name1", Description = "text1");
            WorkoutCategories.Add(new WorkoutCategory() { Name = "name2", Description = "text2");
            WorkoutCategories.Add(new WorkoutCategory() { Name = "name3", Description = "text3"); 
        }
    }
```

Third, you can bind this `ViewModel` (MyViewModel) to the `MainPage.xaml.cs` file.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then you can use the data by using the Binding method in the MainPage.xaml.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp7"
             x:Class="MauiApp7.MainPage">


    <ListView  x:Name="WorkoutCategoriesListView" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" ItemsSource="{x:Binding WorkoutCategories}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >

                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"
                          Detail="{Binding Description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess in your Mainpage you should do it:
InitializeComponent();
BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
then it will work!